# Question about two logic formulas

Tags: logic

How the two following equivalence/relation can be proved?

> **I**) $$(p→q)⇔¬p∨q$$
>   **II**)$$(p→q∧r)⇒(p→r)$$
>   The book I'm reading says that both of this equivalences can be proved without using truth table, but I 
>   still cannot find a way to do that, specially the first one.

Comment: If you do not use truth table, you ahve to use a proof system : axioms+rules, Natural deduction, Tableau, etc.

Comment: What is the proof system used in your textbook ?

Comment: See e.g. [Material Implication](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Material_Implication/Formulation_1) for the first one.

Comment: The second one is **not** an equivalence.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA I checked the link abd there also truth table has been used.

Comment: But there is also a [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Material_Implication/Formulation_1/Forward_Implication).

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA ,thanks,also can you proof the second one?

Comment: Sure: what is the proof system you are using ? Assume the antecedent and assume $p$: the result is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement **(I)** is a logical equivalence.

\begin{align}
&p \to q\\
&\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee q \tag*{implication law}\\
\end{align}

The second statement **(II)** is a tautology.
\begin{align}
&(p \to q \wedge r) \to (p \to r)\\
&\neg (p \to q \wedge r) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{implication law}\\
&\neg (\neg p \vee (q \wedge r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{implication law}\\
&(\neg \neg p \wedge \neg (q \wedge r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{DeMorgan's law}\\
&(p \wedge \neg (q \wedge r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{double negation law}\\
&(p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{DeMorgan's law}\\
&((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge \neg r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{distributive law}\\
&((p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg \neg p \wedge \neg r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{double negation law}\\
&((p \wedge \neg q) \vee \neg (\neg p \vee r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{DeMorgan's law}\\
&((p \wedge \neg q) \vee \neg (p \to r)) \vee (p \to r) \tag*{implication law}\\
&(p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg (p \to r) \vee (p \to r)) \tag*{associative law}\\
&(p \wedge \neg q) \vee T \tag*{negation law}\\
&T \tag*{domination law}\\
\end{align}